# the status of confusing phrase

Tags: sentence-structure

"Shun them not only in reality, but even in appearance, if you would be well received in good company; for people will always be shy of receiving a man who comes from a place where the plague rages, **let him look ever so healthy**."

From LETTERS TO HIS SON By the EARL OF CHESTERFIELD on the Fine Art of becoming a MAN OF THE WORLD and a GENTLEMAN

Semantically, the highlighted part looks like a verb phrase with the subject being **plague**, I guess, but in that case, the verb **let** seems to be missing -s and a coordinator.

Please elaborate me about the status of the part.

Answer (score 1):

This is an archaic usage of the word "let." You will never see it in modern English.

In this usage, "let him look" means "though he may look."

Comment: Thank you so much for being such a great help. I vaguely thought "though" should be needed semantically. I didn't know that let was used in such a way.